# Default no-set category with content regrouping in Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I created a content regrouping category in my Google Analytics administration with a tracking code.

My problem is that only few pages are correctly regrouped when I check reports. More of 90% of pages are stored in the "(no set)" category. When I check the list of pages in "(no set)".

For example, this is a page listed in the "(no set)" category: http://www.tousvoisins.fr/roubaix/agenda-brocante-vide-grenier

You can see in the source that the tracking code is here, so why is this page considered as "(no set)" ?

```
ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'event');
```

Why are 90% of my pages ignored, even if they have the proper tracking code?

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the contentgroup after the pageview call. This affects all calls to the tracker server *after* you are setting the contentgroup, but not the initial pageview. Move it up a notch to it looks like

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'event');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

and you see it working.

Comment: That was obvious, I don't know why I missed that :/ Thank you, it works ;)